# JSON Data not appearing on marker in Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to Load my JSON data to appear on Google map markers. I have used Jquery getJSON method to call the JSON data from a server. But the map is appearing but not the markers. Here's the codes

```js
 var map;
    
    function initialize() {
   
        var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.003389000000, -82.429500000000),
                zoom: 5,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
        $.getJSON('http://tripleclickstudio.com/json/file.json?callback=?', function (json1) {
   
            $.each(json1.ResponseData, function (key, data) {

                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.CoordinateY, data.CoordinateX),
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: data.BuildingName
                    }),
                    details = data.BuildingName + ", " + data.Location + ".";
                
            });

        });
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
       
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, details);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="map" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

this is the link of my JSON file [JSON](http://tripleclickstudio.com/json/file.json) file. So, Here's the thing, I want JSON data coordinates to show as a marker in google map. So, Any so if any one tells me what the mistake i have made and what need to be done to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the browsers developer tools console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `?callback=?` from the json url.

That syntax is for JSON**P**, and your file contents are JSON.